# Trouble Saving Excel ony my computer using c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I have a app that should create a excel spreadsheet and save it. The app works runs without any problems on other machines, including my bosses computer(he has the same ver of office and VS as me). I don't know if this is relevant but I have office 2013 and VS 2012. 
Edit I'm trying to save as a .xls (exel 97').

```
 SNIPIT
 public static bool XLSaveAs(ref Excel._Workbook oWBTemplate, string FileName)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo x = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName);
        if (x.Exists)
        {
            try
            {
                x.Delete();
            }
            catch
            {
                MyControls.MsgFunctions.WarningMsg("Make sure " + FileName + " is not open.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        try
        {
           if(FileName.Contains(".xlsx"))
                oWBTemplate.SaveAs(FileName);
            else
                //Error occurs here
                oWBTemplate.SaveAs(FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);

        }
        catch
        {
            MyControls.MsgFunctions.WarningMsg("Unable to save " + FileName);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

If I take out the try catch statement this is the error I get.

```
ERROR
COMException as unhandled
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Comment: This article can help you: http://www.made4dotnet.com/Default.aspx?tabid=141&aid=15

Comment: I don't think this is it. Everything is in English by default. There is no reason that I can think of that would change the default language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.
I had incorrect permissions to edit the folder that excel was writing too. 
Adding full control to the folder resolved the issue. 
Also the command  oWBTemplate.SaveAsCopy() could help if you have a similar issue.